# Meaning of the sentence "What you're not up on, you're down on"?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I do not understand the meaning of this sentence: "What you're not up on, you're down on."

Comment: There seem to be different explanations. [Warner, in The words of Extraordinary Women](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7u7Q75shOlQC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22What+you%27re+not+up+on,+you%27re+down+on.%22&source=bl&ots=mw_8VAFTXX&sig=HVdZi6V5qn2_d2Z9d28JDd5nAGI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh8eCK2fbRAhVFIcAKHRpyB10Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22What%20you're%20not%20up%20on%2C%20you're%20down%20on.%22&f=false),  gives her views. Please show your own research.

Comment: What do you think it's saying? What research have you done? Where did you hear/see the phrase?

Answer (score 2):

This aphorism plays on the directional antonyms *up* and *down*, each of which is used in its own non-directional idiom.

To be **up on** something is to be familiar or knowledgeable about it. To be **down on** something is to disapprove of it. Here's an [illustration](https://books.google.com/books?id=gg0CiGmm1OIC&pg=PA190&dq=%22not%20up%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrqKuao_fRAhWd2YMKHTBoBBYQ6AEIQjAH#v=onepage&q=%22not%20up%20on%22&f=false) of the former:

> One reviewer for the North American Review, who was obviously not **up on** his Puritan history, objects to the novel....

That is, the reviewer was ignorant of the relevant history. 
And [one](https://books.google.com/books?id=KX08AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT353&dq=%22down%20on%20love%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEnP20pffRAhWISCYKHZfbCxEQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=%22down%20on%20love%22&f=false) for the opposite direction:

> As the punk movement's identity came into sharper focus over the coming months, it revealed itself to be very much **down on** love and longterm or monogamous relationships.

So punk rockers didn't think much of traditional romantic relationships.

Putting things together when you're *not **up on** something, you're  **down on** it* means that you disapprove of what things you don't know about. In other words, the default position of ignorance is disapproval.

I can trace the usage back online to the 1972 edition of [*Saga*](https://ia800504.us.archive.org/2/items/169pullp3925/169pullp3925_bw.pdf), the yearbook of the Warren Travis White High School of Dallas, Texas. Under his senior class picture, David Lawrence Teddlie has imparted

> Prejudice is being **down on what we are not up on**.